# How can I locate the same highest digit?

Tags: c

This code can locate the same digit in a multiple numbering system. The problem I have is that how can I locate the same highest digit if there is another same digit but lower?

**Example Output**

Can locate the same digit

```
Enter the random number: 32432
Greatest digit that occurred more than once = 3
```

Cannot locate the same highest digit because the program can only locate the lowest

```
Enter the random number: 34745676
Greatest digit that occurred more than once = 4
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    int counts[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int max = 0;
    printf("Enter the random number: ");
    while(c=getc(stdin)){
        if (c=='\n') break;
        counts[c-'0']++;
    }
    for(int i=3; i<8; i++) {
        if(counts[i] > counts[max]) max=i;
    }
    printf("Greatest digit that occurred more than once = %i",max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) { if (counts[i] > 1) {max = i; break; }}` ??

Comment: Why do you only check indexes 3 to 7 instead of 0 to 9? Anyway, your code would work if you change to `>=`. Otherwise it saves the _first_ digit with the highest count, not the _max_ - which is an issue only when there are 2 or more digits with the same max count.

Comment: You want the location of highest digit in a number with lowest place value? Or is it the just the highest digit at any location?

Comment: what does that mean? *another same digit but lower?* The output of your program mentiones something different than you asked: "Greatest digit that occured more than once"

Comment: I've located the lowest digit, The question is, how can I located the highest same digit if there's another lowest same digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions

You `for` loop runs from `3 to 8` which means it does not scan every cell of the array. Even if you scan it from `0 to 9` you will still not be able to get the output you want.

---

### Explanation

If i understood corectly, for the input `34745676` the correct result is `7`.
If that's the case you have to change your `for` in some way, because right now as soon as it `finds the max value` the `condition won't be true` if another digit later (which means higher digit) has the `same value` in order to change the value of `max`.

---

### One Solution

Change your `for` loop to:

```c
int max = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    if (counts[i] >= counts[max]) 
        max = i;
```

---

### Demonstration

With input = `34745676` your array will look something like this after the `while` loop:

```
counts[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0 }
```

Since the `condition` inside `for` is `true` if there is a `greater` value or the `same` value from the current max value, 2 >= 2 is true, hence the assignment `max = i` will occur on equal values as well and since the array  is `scanned 0 to 9`, position of higher digit will be assigned last each time even if there is the same value on a lower digit.

Answer (score 3):

- Rather then search only for digits 3 to 7, search digits 0 to 9.
- Look for counts > 1
- Recognize that there may be no solution with a digit that occurs 2 or more times.
- There may exist more than 1 digit with the same max count greater than 1.  Below simply reports the first one.  You may want something different.
- Use an `int c` to distinguish the 257 different results from `getc()`.
- Be prepared to handle input that is not a digit nor `'\n'`.
- Append a `'\n'` to output.

...

```
// char c;
int c;
int counts[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int max = 0;
printf("Enter the random number: ");
while(c=getc(stdin)){
    // if (c=='\n') break;
    if (!isdigit(c)) break;
    counts[c-'0']++;
}
// for(int i=3; i<8; i++) {
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { // Note 1
    // if(counts[i] > counts[max]) max=i;
    if(counts[i] > 1 && counts[i] > counts[max]) max=i; // Note 2
}
if (counts[max] > 1) {
  printf("Greatest digit that occurred more than once = %i\n",max);
} else {
  printf("Greatest digit that occurred more than once did not occur\n", max);
}
```

Note 1: Could start at 1 as 0 is the default `max`.

Note 2: Could omit the `counts[i] > 1 &&` as that consideration is tested after the loop.  Left it in here as conceptually we only want to consider cases where the count is > 1.